# Stop loop in import

Tags: python, multithreading, import, pyqt5

I am making a custom console/shell window module using pyqt5 I have basically everything working but when I import it the whole entire script freezes because of a loop in the module that I import.
This is the module that gets imported:

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit


class SpamWorker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, console: QTextEdit):
        super().__init__()
        self.console = console

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            self.console.append('SPAM!')


class Printer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Printer, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('window.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Console+")
        self.thread_pool = QThreadPool()

        self.thread_pool.start(SpamWorker(self.Console))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Printer()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

how can I import it without it freezing?

Comment: 1) Avoid putting unnecessary information and please just focus on the problem, 2) There is no need for them to explain why they give the DVs as already discussed in SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not

Comment: @eyllanesc Alright my bad thank you!

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc alright thank you so much for all the help with formatting and whatnot!